# Why actions & actionsType are in seperate in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In Redux why should keep the action file and action type separately. There is an action type which is already there inside the action Object then why again separate file for type?

Answer (score 0):

While you don't *technically* need to have a separate "types" file for defining action types, it's a pretty common convention. From the Redux docs (https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducingboilerplate#actions) they list a number of benefits to this pattern:

> It helps keep the naming consistent because all action types are
>   gathered in a single place.
>
> Sometimes you want to see all existing actions before working on a new
>   feature. It may be that the action you need was already added by
>   somebody on the team, but you didn't know.
>
> The list of action types that were added, removed, and changed in a
>   Pull Request helps everyone on the team keep track of scope and
>   implementation of new features.
>
> If you make a typo when importing an action constant, you will get
>   undefined. Redux will immediately throw when dispatching such an
>   action, and you'll find the mistake sooner.

In the end it's up to you on how you decide to implement things in your project.

Comment: Hi Thanks!!! Eventually keeping those Action Types Separately only for others (i mean team in git ) will come to know that some new actions have added am i right???There is nothing techinical behind this right???

Comment: There's nothing technical behind splitting up actions and types into separate files, it's just a very common pattern you'll come across.

Comment: Cool...Thanks:-)